# Viewpager подтормаживает

Tags: java, android

Использую viewpager для просмотра картинок из SD карты снятые на камеру, 
проблема в том что он подтормаживает когда листаешь сразу два или больше раз, как можно это обойти, использую этот адаптер

```
private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position);

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return files.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно он долго свайпается из-за того что на onCreate() и onCreateView() выполняются длительные операции?

Comment: просто вставка картинки

Comment: Это и есть длительная операция, покажи как именно

Comment: View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, null);

        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(FullscreenActivity.files.get(pageNumber).getPath(), bmOptions);        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: не получилось нормально вставить нормально код, в общем просто находится вьюшка и нахожу картинку на карте уже есть готовый массив путей и названий картинок, и присваиваю его вьюшке,

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeFile() это очень длительная операция, ее нужно выносить в фоновый поток. Ну или правильнее всего задействовать библиотеку которая сама все сделает - `ImageLoader` или `Glide`, ищите на гитхабе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);// это позволит загружать не по одной странице слева и справа от текущей во viewPager, а по две.
```

Попробуйте так, если не поможет, попробуйте еще поставить три вместо двух.

Comment: да помогло спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Лучший, ИМХО конечно, способ решения подобной задачи, это использование широко известной в узких кругах библиотеки [Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), который подгружает в асинхронном потоке изображения по мере их чтения, вставляя для скорости стубы картинок. В этом случае вам не придется мучиться с настройками пейджера и прочими премудростями.

Comment: использую UIL выдает exception     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [/storage/extSdCard/Android/data/kz.tanikin.photo/files/20.4.2015.jpg]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))

Comment: каким `URI` вы его кормите? Такое ощущение что вы ему даете какой-то `URI` с неизвестным ему протоколом

Comment: ага вы правы, подставил file:// работает